# Flask Custom jinja2 extension caching template states after new request

Tags: flask, jinja2

I'm Looking to create a similar custom extension to push any javascript code blocks to a designated area on the page or below footer.

My version works using Python 3.6,Flask and Jinja 2.9. However I have a major
issue that occurs after changing the line number or content within the blocks.
The content will appear multiple times on render.

```
from jinja2 import nodes
from jinja2.ext import Extension

class JavascriptBuilderExtension(Extension):
    tags = set(['push'])

    def __init__(self, environment):
        super(JavascriptBuilderExtension, self).__init__(environment)
        self._myScope = {}
        environment.extend(
            pull = self._myScope
            )
    def parse(self, parser):
        """Parse tokens """
        tag = parser.stream.__next__()
        args = [parser.parse_expression(), nodes.Const(tag.lineno)]
        body = parser.parse_statements(['name:endpush'], drop_needle=True)
        callback = self.call_method('compiled', args)
        return nodes.CallBlock(callback,[], [], body).set_lineno(tag.lineno)

    def compiled(self,tagname,linenum,caller):
        tagname = "{}_{}".format( tagname, linenum)
        self._myScope[tagname] = caller()
        return "<!-- moved {} from line {} -->".format(tagname,linenum)
```

My template code looks like this

```
<html> <head></head> <body> <h1>Test template</h1>
{% push 'js' %} X {% endpush %}
{% push 'html' %} Z {% endpush %}
{% push 'js' %} Y {% endpush %}
{{ pull }}
</body> </html>
```

My rendered output is below:

```
<html> <head></head> <body> <h1>Test template</h1>
name = hyper testing jinja
date = right now
<!-- moved js_4 from line 4 -->
<!-- moved html_5 from line 5 -->
<!-- moved js_6 from line 6 -->
{'js_4': ' X ', 'html_5': ' Z ', 'js_6': ' Y '}
</body> </html>
```

**The Problem happens after I change the template block line number or content.**

**After changing content and line numbers**

```
<html> <head></head> <body> <h1>Test template</h1>
{% push 'js' %} ABC {% endpush %}

{% push 'html' %} Z {% endpush %}

{% push 'js' %} 123{% endpush %}
{{ pull }}
</body> </html>
```

**Render changed blocks now has prior content**

```
<html> <head></head> <body> <h1>Test template</h1>
name = hyper testing jinja
date = right now
<!-- moved js_4 from line 4 -->
<!-- moved html_7 from line 7 -->
<!-- moved js_9 from line 9 -->
{'js_4': ' X ABC', 'html_5': ' Z ', 'js_6': ' Y ','js_9':'123','html_7':'Z'}
</body> </html>
```

This issue causes duplicate content to be added into the response.

Is there a way to call the extension on ever page request to re-parse the template for new changes? or Possible to not cache the enclosed extension blocks?

I have already tried adding the code below to auto reload templates but does not help the issue.

`app.jinja_env.auto_reload = True`

### Update: Added link to test code

[Jinja custom extension test code](https://gist.github.com/hyperking/ee1c3e01ac6707de415eb332abc9f79f)

It appears that calling `render_template_string` doesn't cache and renders properly when changes are made. Not sure why `render_template` method caches.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the issue, it is an issue with flask environment initialization which happens when you add the template processor. But I am not able to get the `{{ pull }}` part working one mine. Can you share the complete code so I can test the approach? I have a possible fix

Comment: @tarun i will add the link shortly. Try adding pull to the context. ' pull=app.jinja_env.pull '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okie, so this took a lot of hours to figure out, because there were two issues.

**Flask doesn't reload templates when extension are added**

```
env = app.jinja_env
env.add_extension("flaskext.JavascriptBuilderExtension")
```

When you add the extension like above, then `jinja_env` gets created even before the first request. This internally check if `TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD` is set or not, if it is not set then value of debug is checked. But as of now even our `app.run(debug=True)` has not been called. So that is why templating reloading doesn't get enabled

Solution is to add config manually before accessing the `jinja_env`

```
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
app.config['EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING'] = True
env = app.jinja_env
env.add_extension("flaskext.JavascriptBuilderExtension")
```

**Using request context instead of global context**

Next the Extension is only initialized once. So you have used below code

```
def __init__(self, environment):
    super(JavascriptBuilderExtension, self).__init__(environment)
    self._myScope = {}
    environment.extend(
        pull = self._myScope
        )
```

The `_myScope` variable is created at extension level which will remain there till flask is running. So you are creating a variable and sharing data across any page render even with different request. The need is to use context that is only live till the request is. For this one can use `jinja2.nodes.ContextReference`

Also since the data is now available only in context we need to use `{% pull %}` instead of `{{ pull }}`. I could not inject a variable into context from the extension. There might be a way but my experimentation around that failed. So below is the final class I used

```
from jinja2 import nodes
from jinja2.ext import Extension
from jinja2.nodes import ContextReference


class JavascriptBuilderExtension(Extension):
    tags = set(['push','pull'])

    def __init__(self, environment):
        super(JavascriptBuilderExtension, self).__init__(environment)
        self._myScope = {}

    def parse(self, parser):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def preprocess(self, source, name, filename=None):
        return super(JavascriptBuilderExtension, self).preprocess(source, name, filename)

    def parse(self, parser):
        """Parse tokens """
        tag = parser.stream.__next__()
        ctx_ref = ContextReference()

        if tag.value == "push":
            args = [ctx_ref, parser.parse_expression(), nodes.Const(tag.lineno)]
            body = parser.parse_statements(['name:endpush'], drop_needle=True)
            callback = self.call_method('compiled', args)
        else:
            body = []
            callback = self.call_method('scope', [ctx_ref])

        return nodes.CallBlock(callback, [], [], body).set_lineno(tag.lineno)

    def scope(self, context, caller):
        return str(context.vars["_myScope"])

    def compiled(self, context, tagname, linenum, caller):
        tagname = "{}_{}".format(tagname, linenum)

        if "_myScope" not in context.vars:
            context.vars["_myScope"] = {}

        context.vars["_myScope"][tagname] = caller()

        return "<!-- moved {} from line {} -->".format(tagname, linenum)
```

Key changes were
- Get the context using `ctx_ref = ContextReference()`
- Pass it in the callback args
- Create `_myScope` in context if one doesn't exist
- Make a separate render for `pull`

Now when I make the request the html generated is

```
<html> <head></head> <body> <h1>Test template</h1>
<!-- moved js_2 from line 2 -->

<!-- moved html_4 from line 4 -->

<!-- moved js_6 from line 6 -->

{'js_6': Markup(u' DEF '), 'html_4': Markup(u' Z '), 'js_2': Markup(u' ABC ')}
</body> </html>
```

Comment: Great solution! I'm using python 3.6 and getting an error` AttributeError: 'TokenStream' object has no attribute 'next' ` I needed to change 'next' method into `__next__()`

I will test your code more and post my results. Do you have any thoughts as to why `render_template_string` operates differently?

Comment: change it to `__next__` I tested in python2.7 that is why may be

Comment: I just tested it and it works for me in python 3 with that changed. edited the answer

Comment: Can you clarify the conditional statement in your code?

`
if tag.value == "push":
            args = [ctx_ref, parser.parse_expression(), nodes.Const(tag.lineno)]
            body = parser.parse_statements(['name:endpush'], drop_needle=True)
            callback = self.call_method('compiled', args)
        else:
            body = []
            callback = self.call_method('scope', [ctx_ref])

`

I want to understand why template variables couldn't be used when `render_template_string` works?

Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: The if statement is to implement pull and push in the same extension. The variable didn't work in template because we need to inject the value in the context, which i was not able to from the extension. It may be possible but i could not find a way yet

Comment: How would we access values from the context object?
`{% pull['js'] %}` does not work and neither does `{% pull.get('js') %}` or `{% pull.js %}`

Comment: That needs the context injection as I mentioned. I am not yet sure if it can be done or not and if yes then how

Comment: We have a stable solution and a way to access the context objects by calling `{% pull 'js' %}`.  Refer to the github gist for updated code. Thanks a Million for your help!

Comment: Cool. Thanks for sharing